# The name 'toAdresses' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, variables

The error is the following: `CS0103: The name 'toAdresses' does not exist in the current context`

In the following code:

```
public bool myFunction()
    {
        string toAddress;

        toAddress = "paul@gmail.com,jhon@gmail.com";        // for testing

        int firstCharacter = toAddress.IndexOf(',');

        if (firstCharacter != -1)
        {
            string[] toAdresses = toAddress.Split(',');
        }
        else 
        { 
            string[] toAdresses = new string[]{toAddress};
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < toAdresses.Length; i++)     // here is the error with toAdresses.Length
        {
            // do this
        }
    }
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Terrible variable naming :(

Comment: If you are interested more in coding, Code Complete 2 is a great book and discusses the importance of variable naming.  It's something that comes with experience and nothing to be ashamed of if you are a new developer just learning.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The scope of your variable is restricted to the block you defined it in.  In this case, toAddresses is defined in your if/else block and loses scope when you exit that block.

Placing the variable definition outside the block will expand the scope of it.

ex:

```
 string[] toAdresses;
 if (firstCharacter != -1)
 {
     toAdresses = toAddress.Split(',');
 }
 else 
 { 
     toAdresses = new string[]{toAddress};
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You've defined the `toAddresses` array inside of a conditional. That means that when you leave that block, the variable is no longer in scope (even if you define it in both the `if` and `else` blocks.

Instead, you should define the variable outside of the block and only initialize it inside:

```
string[] toAddresses;

if(firstCharacter != -1)
{
    toAddresses = toAddress.Split(',');
}
else
{
    toAddresses = new string[] { toAddress };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to move toAdresses declaration outside of the if-else block or just get rid of it:

```
public bool myFunction()
{
    string toAddress;

    toAddress = "paul@gmail.com,jhon@gmail.com";        // for testing

    int firstCharacter = toAddress.IndexOf(',');

    string[] toAdresses = firstCharacter != -1
                            ? toAddress.Split(',')
                            : new string[]{toAddress};

    for (int i = 0; i < toAdresses.Length; i++)     // here is the error with toAdresses.Length
    {
        // do this
    }
}
```